# Moving vector pointer to derived class of vector in C++?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector, move

I want to move the pointer of a vector to my the vector of the A object (this). I want to do this because I use my help vector (for mergesort) and I want the values of the help vector in the original vector. I however only want to use 1 operation (so it should be done with a move, no copying of elements).

This is the code I use:

```
template<class T>
class A:public vector<T> {
    public:
        void fillAndMove();

        vector<T> help;
}

template<class T>
void A<T>:fillAndMove() {
    // Fill a help array with random values
    help.resize(2);
    help[0] = 5;
    help[1] = 3;

    // This line doesn't work
    *this = move(help);
}
```

I get following error:

```
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'A<int>' and 'std::remove_reference<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&>::type {aka std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >}')
```

I think the problem is that the help vector needs to be casted to a class A object but I don't know how I should do it. Anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement move assigment operator, which will do it in O(1).

```
template<class T>
class A :public vector<T> {
public:
    void fillAndMove();

    vector<T> help;

    A & operator=(std::vector<T> && rhs)
    {
        static_cast<vector<T>&>(*this) = move(rhs);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

It will allow to assign normal vectors to your A class as well though, which will keep `help` vector unchanged, thus you might want to make this operator `private` and implement move assigment operator for A class public.

```
    test = std::vector<int>{ 5,6 }; // possible - should assigment operator be private?
```

Not possible with this code:

```
template<class T>
class A :public vector<T> {
public:
    void fillAndMove();

    vector<T> help;

    A & operator=(A && rhs)
    {
        // Move as you want it here, probably like this:
        help = std::move(rhs.help);
        static_cast<vector<T>&>(*this) = move(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    A & operator=(std::vector<T> && rhs)
    {
        static_cast<vector<T>&>(*this) = move(rhs);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Also, when doing it you should implement move constructor as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You have to overload operator assignment if you want to use it that way

```
A & operator=(const std::vector<T> & rhs)
{
    for(auto it : help)
    {
        this->push_back(it);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

**[Working example here.](http://ideone.com/oY9WKg)**

Comment: But that means you move every element of the vector, my goal is to move the pointer of the vector itself and not to move every pointer within the vector.

What you are doing requires O(n) operations and I only want O(1) operations. Is this possible?

Comment: Ive just tried everuthing i know but i couldnt solve it with O(1) sorry.